# Check Dictionary WIth ObjectForKey IsEqualToString not working

Tags: nsmutabledictionary

i have this code and searched the internet and find it ok but its not working with me

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    .....
    NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"]);

    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {

       NSLog(@"Done");

    }
```

The NSLog Shows Y Which Should Work With if statment

Comment: May we see the code where @"Y" is inserted into the dictionary?

Comment: i have them on array which i converted from POST response                        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSArray *outputArray=[data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

Comment: then i convert it to Dictionary for (NSString *s in outputArray) { NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"]; [dict setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]; } I Have NSlog the [dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"] and show on console Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
 [dict setObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1] ...
```

i think this is adding the strings to the dictionary as objects.  The NSLog line is working because NSLog sends each object it is passed the "description" message to convert it to its string value.  you can do the same thing.

try changing this:

```
if ([[dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"] isEqualToString:@"Y"])
```

to this:

```
if ([[[dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"] description] isEqualToString:@"Y"])
```

That would get the string value of the object returned by objectForKey: before doing the comparison.

If you think there might be a white space throwing off the compare, trim the string before comparing, like this:

```
if ([[[dict objectForKey:@"STATUS"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@"Y"])
```

Comment: When you do [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] what does s look like?  Could there possibly be a space in the string containing Y?  Try changing NSLog(@"%@", ...  to NSLog(@"-->%@<--", this would show if there are spaces before or after Y.

Comment: NSLog show -->Y
<--
is it a lot of space or just the console ?

Comment: its look like didnt show right here but i see it on console in 2 line   like this Line 1-->Y and on line 2<--

Comment: You have a newline character throwing off the string compare.  This needs to be trimmed from the string before the compare.  I've edited my answer to include this trimming code.

Comment: Yes u are right coz i create the array with this code NSArray *outputArray=[data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; which as you said add new line Thanks @tetsuo000 its work You Are my Hero

Comment: Actually, componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n" is a string split operation that i would *think* would have removed the \n since that is the separator string.  So that is a bit mysterious to me, but i'm glad your issue is solved!